# Does Ubuntu Customization Kit work on all Ubuntu Versions? (15.04+)

Tags: 15.04, customization, uck

I'm trying to create a customized Ubuntu install, but I'm not sure if its compatibly to Ubuntu 15.04. I know its compatible with 14.04 LTS, but is it with 15.04, since Development stopped 2 years ago. Thanks!

Comment: I've created an image today, Ubuntu Mate 15.10. You can give a look at issues/solutions @ my post [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/699282/ubuntu-customization-kit-vs-ubuntu-mate-15-10).