# Ubuntu Customization Kit vs. Ubuntu Mate 15.10

Tags: upgrade, mate, uck

I got some stops from using UCK creating a Mate 15.10 image.

I have:

```
uck 2.4.7-0ubuntu2

LSB Version:    core-2.0-amd64:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-amd64:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:security-4.0-amd64:security-4.0-noarch:security-4.1-amd64:security-4.1-noarch
```

There is serie of expansion errors in the main script, and unmet dependencies.
How to make it works?

Which changes are needed in order to make it create the ISO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UCK main script needs some updates.

**Issue 1:**

Missing dependency: gfxboot-theme-ubuntu

Solve it with:

```
sudo apt-get install gfxboot-theme-ubuntu
```

**Issue 2:**

A mess with locales. I just didn't check locales I still have installed (no check at all). UCK will take them from the current installation.

**Issue 3:**

Missing files.

I give you here my modified `/usr/lib/uck/customization-profiles/localized_cd/customize_iso`, in order to make it works (changes from the original one are tagged "HS"):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

###################################################################################
# UCK - Ubuntu Customization Kit                                                  #
# Copyright (C) 2006-2010 UCK Team                                                #
#                                                                                 #
# UCK is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify                     #
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by            #
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or               #
# (at your option) any later version.                                             #
#                                                                                 #
# UCK is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,                          #
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of                  #
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the                   #
# GNU General Public License for more details.                                    #
#                                                                                 #
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License               #
# along with UCK.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.                    #
###################################################################################

# NAME:
#    customize_iso -- customize iso image outside of root FS
#
# SYNOPSIS:
#    customize_iso [remaster_home] [customization_scripts_dir]
#
# DESCRIPTION:
#    This procedure performs additional customization that needs to
#    happen outside of the image of the root file system:
#        - Configuration of the boot environment
#            - isolinux configuration
#            - gfxboot configuration (language/keyboard support!)
#            - propagation of a new kernel/initrd
#            - Simple bootmanager (directory "install" in image)
#        - Configuration of additional resources outside the root FS
#            - Add-Ons (like sample document/music/video files)
#            - More Add-Ons (like OSS for Win / Mac)
#
# NOTES:
#    Execution of the procedure may require Internet access to download
#    the source of the latest version gfxboot-theme-ubuntu.
#
#    If a local copy of gfxboot-theme-ubuntu is available in the remaster
#    home, it will be used instead of a (possibly updated) download.

SCRIPT_DIR=`dirname "$0"`
REMASTER_HOME=${1:-~/tmp}
SCRIPT_DIR=${2-$REMASTER_HOME/customization-scripts}
ISO_REMASTER_DIR="$REMASTER_HOME/remaster-iso"
REMASTER_DIR="$REMASTER_HOME/remaster-root"
BOOT_LANG=`cat "$SCRIPT_DIR/livecd_locale"`

function failure()
{
    echo "$@"
    exit 1
}

function get_latest_kernel()
{
    set -- $(ls "$REMASTER_DIR"/boot/vmlinuz* 2>/dev/null |
        sed -e "s@$REMASTER_DIR/boot/@@" |
        tr --  '-.' '\t' |
        sort --key=2 --key=3 --key=4  --key=5 --numeric-sort |
        tail -n1 )
    [ "$1" = "vmlinuz" ] && echo "$REMASTER_DIR/boot/$1-$2.$3.$4-$5-$6"
}

# Create a temporary directory to assemble the gfxboot stuff in
BUILD_DIR=`mktemp -d`
if [ -d $REMASTER_HOME/gfxboot-theme-ubuntu ]
then
    cp -r $REMASTER_HOME/gfxboot-theme-ubuntu "$BUILD_DIR" ||
        failure "Cannot copy gfxboot-theme-ubuntu to $BUILD_DIR"
    pushd "$BUILD_DIR" >/dev/null ||
        failure "Cannot change directory to $BUILD_DIR"
else
    pushd "$BUILD_DIR" >/dev/null ||
        failure "Cannot change directory to $BUILD_DIR"
    #-----HS (1)-->
    #DISTRO_CODENAME=`cd "$ISO_REMASTER_DIR"/dists && find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | grep '/' | cut -d '/' -f2` ||
    #   failure "Unable to identify Ubuntu distro codename"
     DISTRO_CODENAME="$(lsb_release -c|awk '{print $2}')"||
        failure "Unable to identify Ubuntu distro codename"
    #-----HS (1)--<
    APT_SOURCES_TMP_DIR=`mktemp -d`
    wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/$DISTRO_CODENAME/main/source/Sources.gz -O "$APT_SOURCES_TMP_DIR"/Sources.gz
    #-----HS (2)-->
    #GFXBOOT_THEME_UBUNTU_SOURCE_PACKAGE=http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gfxboot-theme-ubuntu/$(zgrep gz "$APT_SOURCES_TMP_DIR"/Sources.gz | grep gfxboot-theme-ubuntu | sed -n 1p | awk '{ print $3 }')
    GFXBOOT_THEME_UBUNTU_SOURCE_PACKAGE=http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gfxboot-theme-ubuntu/$(dpkg -l|grep gfxboot-theme-ubuntu|awk '{print $2"_"$3"_"$4".deb"}')
    #-----HS (2)--<
    wget $GFXBOOT_THEME_UBUNTU_SOURCE_PACKAGE ||
        failure "Unable to download gfxboot-theme-ubuntu source package from $GFXBOOT_THEME_UBUNTU_SOURCE_PACKAGE"
    #-----HS (3)-->
    #tar xfz *.tar.gz ||
    tar xfz *.tar.gz
    dpkg -x *.deb . ||
        failure "Unable to extract gfxboot-theme-ubuntu source package"
    #-----HS (3)--<
fi

# Build the gfx boot theme
    #-----HS (4)-->
cd usr/share
    #-----HS (4)--<
cd gfxboot-theme-ubuntu
cd po
ln -s pt.po pt_PT.po
cd ..
##if [ "$BOOT_LANG" = "pt_PT" ]; then
##  make DEFAULT_LANG="pt" || failure "Failed to build gfxboot theme"
##else
    make DEFAULT_LANG="$BOOT_LANG" || failure "Failed to build gfxboot theme"
##fi

# Fix list of languages
pushd boot >/dev/null

# Create regexp that matches all language packs on CD
langpack=""
for langpack in `cat "$SCRIPT_DIR/language_packs"`; do
    if [ -z "$LANGPACKS" ]; then
        LANGPACKS="$langpack"
    else
        LANGPACKS="$LANGPACKS|$langpack"
    fi
done

# Rewrite langlist
cat "$SCRIPT_DIR/livecd_locales" >langlist
popd >/dev/null

# Copy to isolinux in image directory
cp -af boot/* "$ISO_REMASTER_DIR/isolinux/" ||
    failure "Error while copying boot files to $ISO_REMASTER_DIR/isolinux"

popd >/dev/null

# Cleanup
[ "$BUILD_DIR" != "/" ] && rm -rf "$BUILD_DIR"

# Copy kernel and initrd, in case it was changed during installation
VMLINUZ=$(get_latest_kernel)
if [ "$VMLINUZ" != "" ]
then
    INITRD="$REMASTER_DIR"/boot/initrd.img-$(echo `basename $VMLINUZ` | cut -d'-' -f 2-)
    if [ -e "$VMLINUZ" -a -e "$INITRD" ]
    then
        echo "Updating kernel:"
        echo "  kernel=$VMLINUZ"
        echo "  initrd=$INITRD"
        cp -f "$VMLINUZ" "$ISO_REMASTER_DIR/casper/vmlinuz"
        cp -f "$INITRD" "$ISO_REMASTER_DIR/casper/initrd.gz"
    else
        echo "Not updating kernel as initrd not present"
    fi
fi

# Misc fixup for Karmic
pushd "$ISO_REMASTER_DIR"/isolinux >/dev/null

# What used to be called "message" is now called "bootlogo"
if [ -f isolinux.cfg -a -n "`grep "gfxboot bootlogo" isolinux.cfg 2>/dev/null`" ]
then
    if [ -f message ]
    then
        echo "Using bootlogo instead of message"
        mv message bootlogo
    fi
fi

# What used to be a gzipped initrd now is a lzma compressed initrd
if [ -f text.cfg ] || [ -f txt.cfg ]
then
    # At least one of the .cfg file will be missing. Drop error message.
    lzused=`grep initrd.lz text.cfg txt.cfg 2>/dev/null`
    lzmacmd=`which lzma`
    if [ -n "$lzused" ]
    then
        if [ -n "$lzmacmd" ]
        then
            if [ -f ../casper/initrd.gz ]
            then
                pushd "$ISO_REMASTER_DIR"/casper >/dev/null
                echo "Recompressing initrd from gzip to lzma"
                rm -f initrd.lz
                gunzip <initrd.gz | $lzmacmd >initrd.lz
                rm -f initrd.gz
                popd >/dev/null
            fi
        else
            if [ -f ../casper/initrd.gz ]
            then
                echo "lzma command not installed"
                echo "Switching permanently to gzipped initrd"
                sed -i -e 's/initrd\.lz/initrd.gz/g' text.cfg txt.cfg
                rm -f ../casper/initrd.lz
            else
                : do nothing - no initrd.gz
            fi
        fi
    else
        : do nothing - initrd.lz not used
    fi
fi
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

**Issue 4**

Missing mate terminal for customization operations by command line.

I changed function `run_console()` in file `/usr/lib/uck/customization-profiles/localized_cd/customize`:

```bsh
function run_console()
{
    echo "Starting console application..."

    CONSOLE_APP=`which konsole`
    CONSOLE_APP_OPTIONS=(--caption "UCK customization console" -e /bin/bash)
    if [ "$CONSOLE_APP" = "" ]; then
        CONSOLE_APP=`which gnome-terminal`
        CONSOLE_APP_OPTIONS=(-t "UCK customization console" -e /bin/bash)
    fi
    if [ "$CONSOLE_APP" = "" ]; then
        CONSOLE_APP=`which xfce4-terminal`
        CONSOLE_APP_OPTIONS=(-T "UCK customization console" -e /bin/bash)
    fi
    if [ "$CONSOLE_APP" = "" ]; then
        CONSOLE_APP=`which lxterminal`
        CONSOLE_APP_OPTIONS=(-t "UCK customization console" -e /bin/bash)
    fi
        if [ "$CONSOLE_APP" = "" ]; then
                CONSOLE_APP=`which mate-terminal`
                CONSOLE_APP_OPTIONS=(-t "UCK customization console" -e /bin/bash)
        fi
    if [ "$CONSOLE_APP" = "" ]; then
        CONSOLE_APP=`which xterm`
        CONSOLE_APP_OPTIONS=(-title "UCK customization console" -e /bin/bash)
    fi

    if [ "$CONSOLE_APP" = "" ]; then
        dialog_msgbox "Failure" "Unable to find any console application"
    else
        eval `dbus-launch --sh-syntax --exit-with-session 2>/dev/null`
        $CONSOLE_APP "${CONSOLE_APP_OPTIONS[@]}"
        RESULT=$?
    fi
}
```

See here: https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=1758821